# Sequential execution of functions using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I want to sequentially execute some asynchronous functions based on an array.

I thought this would do it :

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.cast([1,2,3]).reduce(function(_,i){
    console.log("Launching  " + i);
    return Promise.delay(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)).then(function(){
        console.log("Executing  " + i);
    });
},0);
```

but I get

```
Launching  1
Launching  2
Launching  3
Executing  2
Executing  1
Executing  3
```

instead of the desired result which would be

```
Launching  1
Executing  1
Launching  2
Executing  2
Launching  3
Executing  3
```

How can I ensure wholly sequential execution here ?

Note that I know how to do that without promises, I'm only interested in full promises solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of Bluebird. The behavior of `.reduce` was changed in `v1` to work this way:

> Like `.map` and `.filter`, `.reduce` now allows returning promises and thenables from the iteration function.

( [from the changelog](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/changelog.md#100-2014-01-12) )

Please update to the most recent version. This will cause the code to run correctly.

Comment: Yes, upgrading Bluebird to 1.0.8 fixed the problem.

Comment: If anyone is reading this and is "stuck" on a `< v1` version of Bluebird and can't update - let me know and I'll add a `< v1` answer - otherwise, I'd rather not so more people upgrade to modern Bluebird.